# Max difference in a group

Tags: powerbi, dax

For every group I'd like to find the max observation for VarB and subtract the first value in each group of Var A. Max(`VarB` for group1) - FirstObs(`VarA` group1).  Hopefully this makes sense.  Below is the desired results in table form and my attempt at the code

```
 VarA  VarB  Group  Result    Index
  10     11    1   (10-11=-1)   1
  11      4    1   (10-11=-1)   2
 ...
  12     7     1   (10-11=-1)   5
  9     11     2   (9-11=-2)    6
  13      4    2   (9-11=-2)    7
 ...
  11     7     2   (9-11=-2)    11

Maxdiff = 
   VAR CurrGroup = Table1[Group]
   VAR MaxVal = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[VarB]), ALL(Table1), Table1[Group] = CurrGroup)
   VAR MinIndex = CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[Index]), ALL(Table1), Table1[Group] = CurrGroup)
   RETURN LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[VarB], Table1[Group], MaxVal) - 
          LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[VarA], Table1[Index], MinIndex)
```

I get the error "a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to look up the `VarB` value for a `Group` that matches your `MaxVal`. This doesn't make sense since you probably don't want to match a `Group` number to a `VarB` value. It returns multiple values since each group has multiple `VarB` values associated with it.

I think the following is what you are after:

```
MaxDiff = 
    VAR CurrGroup = Table1[Group]
    VAR MaxVal = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[VarB]), ALL(Table1), Table1[Group] = CurrGroup)
    VAR MinIndex = CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[Index]), ALL(Table1), Table1[Group] = CurrGroup)
    RETURN MaxVal - LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[VarA], Table1[Index], MinIndex)
```

This returns `1` and `2` for `[Group]` = `1` and `2`.
(Your subtraction looks backward in your question.)